# File uploaded with JSch is not visible in the target directory

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have written below logic using JSch API to upload a PDF file to an SFTP server. The code executes fine, but I can't see the file in the expected folder.

```java
String localFile = "/usr/local/test.pdf";
String remotePath = "/tmp/test.pdf";

JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts("/home/wasadm/.ssh/known_hosts");
jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT);
jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD);
jschSession.connect(SESSION_TIMEOUT);

Channel sftp = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
sftp.connect(CHANNEL_TIMEOUT);

ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) sftp;

channelSftp.put(localFile, remotePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [`ChannelSftp.put`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is *"the remote destination **file name**"*, not directory name. So like this:

```
String remotePath = "/tmp/test.pdf";
```