# JSCH: Success uploading file but not in the right extension

Tags: java, file-upload, sftp, quarkus, jsch

So I uploaded my file to SFTP directory successfully. But here's the thing. The file uploaded is in "File format" and its name is the same as its directory.

[image]

But the actual file is in .jpg file. I also tried it on a .txt file but it's the same.

[image]

Although, when I manually add ".jpg" or ".txt" on SFTPRoot file, it reads my file and shows the cat picture.

Here's my code:

```
private final SFTPConfig sftpConfig;
private final String KNOWN_HOST = "/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts";
private final String LOCAL_PATH = "C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/";

public void setupJsch(int configType, String fileName) throws JSchException, SftpException {
    log.info("+++++ CONNECTING TO SFTP +++++");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.setKnownHosts(KNOWN_HOST);
    Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(sftpConfig.username(), sftpConfig.remoteHost(), 22);
    jschSession.setPassword(sftpConfig.password());
    jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jschSession.connect();

    Channel channel = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    sftpChannel.connect(60000);
    log.info("+++++ ESTABLISHED CONNECTION +++++");

    try {
        if (configType == 1) {
            log.info("+++++ BEGIN SENDING {} TO SFTP", fileName);
            sendFile(sftpChannel, fileName);
        } else {
            log.info("+++++ BEGIN DOWNLOADING {} FROM SFTP", fileName);
            downloadFile(sftpChannel, fileName);
        }
    } catch (SftpException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Error downloading/sending the file: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    sftpChannel.disconnect();
    jschSession.disconnect();
    log.info("+++++ DISCONNECTED TO SFTP +++++");
}

public void sendFile(ChannelSftp sftpChannel, String fileName) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {
    sftpChannel.put(LOCAL_PATH + fileName, sftpConfig.sftpPath());
}

public void downloadFile(ChannelSftp sftpChannel, String fileName) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {
    sftpChannel.get(sftpConfig.sftpPath()+"/"+filename,LOCAL_PATH);
}
}
```

Also, here's my sftp config:

```
#---- SFTP CONFIGURATIONS
sftp.remote-host=localhost
sftp.username=root
sftp.password=root
sftp.path=/SFTPRoot
```

I also try the File and FileInputStream but it's giving me **No Such File** That's why I'm sticking to earlier approach. Below is my code using input stream.

```
//File file = new File(LOCAL_PATH + fileName);
//log.warn("File {}: Exist? {} : {}, Path = {} ", file.getName(), file.exists(), file.isFile(), file.getPath());
//sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(file), sftpConfig.sftpPath());
```

Did I forget something? Or do something wrong?

Comment: You forgot to add logging for the actual names of the paths used for the transfer, and it looks like you forgot the specify a filename (with extension) for the destination of the transfer.

Comment: See [Can't upload file to SFTP server using JSch - No such file (SftpException)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69016420/850848).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, I just found out the answer by my own.

Simply put the file name in dst. Sample:

```
File file = new File(LOCAL_PATH + fileName);
sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
```

or simply

```
sftpChannel.put(LOCAL_PATH + fileName, <whatever you want to name for your file + extension>);
```

I just realize that JSCH automatically calls the SFTP server directory. So in my case. My default SFTP local server is "/SFTPRoot". So no need to call the SFTPRoot directory and just simply add the filename (or change it to something new. Example: cat.jpg to cutecat.jpg)

Then If I create a folder inside of the server then put a file inside that folder, the code will be like this:

```
sftpChannel.put(LOCAL_PATH + fileName, sftpConfig.homePath() + "/cutecat.jpg");
```

Hope it helps.
my home folder config is like this:

```
sftp.home-path=/Home
```